# Java ImageIO read image in ppm format return null

Tags: java, javax.imageio, ppm

Does javax.imageio.ImageIO read image in PPM format (e.g., rawbits P6) at all?

```
BufferedImage rawimage = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/lena.ppm").getFile()));
```

There is no Exception but `rawimage` is `null`. Other formats like png and jpg work fine.

I have an awkward workaround, by striping off the header and scan ppm file line-by-line.
I am assuming the JAVA JAI (part of JDK now) will do it out-of-box.

Do I miss anything here?

Comment: I don't believe it supports .ppm files, at least not default. Edit: source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, JAI is still not part of the JDK/JRE, it's a separate download/install. And, yes, you will need JAI ImageIO (or other 3rd party plugin, like [my own](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys)) to read PPM, it is not supported out of the box.

[`ImageIO.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)) will return `null` for formats it doesn't support. This is the expected/documented behavior.

You can query the formats you have installed support for, using [`ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#getReaderFormatNames()).

Answer (score 1):

Decoding a PPM file is not natively available:  "[Image I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) has built-in support for GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP."  But you may be able to find a library (or plugin) that has this support, just search for something like  [java ppm imagereader](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+ppm+imagereader).

Answer (score 0):

With the ImageIO plugin (licensed under LGPL) from this page  [PPM (Portable PixMap), PGM, PBM image file java image reader/writer](http://thorntonzone.com/manuals/Compression/Fax,%20IBM%20MMR/MMSC/mmsc/uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/ppm/index.html) you could read/write the rawbit PPM files.

The JAR file would need at least following files

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/services/
META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi
META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi
uk/
uk/co/
uk/co/mmscomputing/
uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/
uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/ppm/
uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/ppm/PPMConstants.class
uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/ppm/PPMImageReader.class
uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/ppm/PPMImageReaderSpi.class
uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/ppm/PPMImageWriter.class
uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/ppm/PPMImageWriterSpi.class
```